# ActiveStorage 5.2.1 - uploaded asset is nil since upload has not finished. How to wait for finished upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I use ActiveStorage for user generated stylesheets which will be uploaded to s3 in order to include them in a custom user styled web page.

So I have a model CustomeTheme

```
has_one_attached :style, dependent: :purge_later
```

and an after_save callback which does the upload after the custom style has been saved

```
self.style.attach(io: File.open(File.join(asset_path, name)), filename: name, content_type: 'text/css')
```

Included in a layout

```
= stylesheet_link_tag url_for(@custom_theme.style)
```

The problem now is, that the user saves the style and and sees a preview of the custom web page but without the custom style (404 at this point of time) since the uploaded to s3 has not finished yet, at least thats what I suppose.

```
to_model delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil

/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:278:in `rescue in method_missing'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:274:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:265:in `handle_model'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:280:in `handle_model_call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-5.2.1/lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb:117:in `url_for'
```

So the question remains unclear to me how could i know that the asset (no matter whether it is a style or an image) is ready to be displayed?

Comment: How are you using the style after saving? you are not showing the code for that. What does the logs show? do you see an anlalyze job running after the save? did you check the file path and the url are correct?

Comment: @arieljuod I just updated the question. The analyze job runs successfully and the upload is in general successful, but too late, that's what I suspect since I can see the style a few requests/seconds later

Answer (score 0):

2 possible approaches:

1. Define a route for upload status checks and then run an interval in Javascript to check for upload status for a given upload id. When it finishes, the endpoint returns the asset URL, which then you can use. (e.g. If the asset is an image, then you just put that on an `<img>` tag `src` attribute).
2. Another approach would be something like what [Delayed Paperclip](https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/) does:

> In the default setup, when you upload an image for the first time and try to display it before the job has been completed, Paperclip will be none the wiser and output the url of the image which is yet to be processed, which will result in a broken image link being displayed on the page.
>
> To have the missing image url be outputted by paperclip while the image is being processed, all you need to do is add a #{attachment_name}_processing column to the specific model you want to enable this feature for.

```
class AddAvatarProcessingToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :avatar_processing, :boolean
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :avatar_processing
  end
end

@user = User.new(avatar: File.new(...))
@user.save
@user.avatar.url #=> "/images/original/missing.png"

# Process job

@user.reload
@user.avatar.url #=> "/system/images/3/original/IMG_2772.JPG?1267562148"
```

Comment: Polling might be difficult here, since i do not get back the job id of active storages upload job id, right?! Furthermore it's a little bit overhead, i dont want the user to poll for an asset upload which should take no longer than 2 s. That's why i d like to run custom_theme.save synchronously and just wait for the upload job to finish.

Comment: @dc10 In that case, the second approach does not using polling. It just defines a path to a "missing.png" image when the asset is still being processed. When it finishes, it would display the link to the actual URL. To answer your question directly of how to know when it is ready to be displayed: You would call "`@user.style.processing?`"